# How are method overloads selected when types are not known at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Say I have the following code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Other stuff...

    public void ApplyEvent<T>(IPublishedEvent<T> evt)
    {
        Handle(evt.Payload);
    }

    protected virtual void Handle(ThingyCreatedEvent evt)
    {
        Code = evt.Code;
        Label = evt.Label;
    }

    protected virtual void Handle<T>(T evt)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            String.Format("Not set to handle {0}", evt.GetType().FullName));
    }
}
```

evt.Payload is of type T.  My hope was to be able to handle methods for specific event types I expect, and have a catch-all method that will throw if an unexpected event type is provided for some reason.

What I've found, though, is that the generic method gets called even if T is of type ThingyCreatedEvent, unless I explicitly cast it:

```
Handle(evt.Payload as ThingyCreatedEvent);
```

I get the same results if, instead of a generic Handle method, I define a Handle method with an Object type parameter.

Can anyone explain this? I'd like to have a better understanding of what's going on here. I would have expected it to dispatch according to the actual type provided at run-time.

Comment: .NET generics are not C++ templates.  C++ templates are not .NET generics.  And neither one provides runtime dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code - including overload resolution - is compiled once, at normal compilation time, and the overload decisions have to be made without any knowledge of what `T` is unless there are constraints on it. The method call `Handle(evt.Payload);` is resolved once with only the knowledge that the type of `evt.Payload` is `T`, so it *has* to resolve to `Handle<T>(T evt)`.

If you really want overload resolution at execution time, and if you're using C# 4, you can use dynamic typing:

```
public void ApplyEvent<T>(IPublishedEvent<T> evt)
{
    dynamic payload = evt.Payload;
    Handle(payload);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - I am using .Net 4, so dynamic it is!

Comment: And, unrelated, Jon and Maciek both - that was really. Really. Quick. Wow.

Comment: @Remi: Not really. It took 3 minutes. I apologise for the delay, and will try to help quicker next time ;)

Comment: @Remi & Jon - Woot! I beat Jon by 1 minute !

Answer (score 4):

Generics are resolved at compile-time - the compiler needs to know what is the type of T. If you're looking to use a type that is going to be resolved at runtime, you should look up the keyword "dynamic".

Comment: Nitpick: `dynamic` is only a *contextual* keyword :)